# Angular-File-Upload does not work with Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-file-upload

I am using Angular File Upload library.

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

and I have been successful in implementing,works in all browsers except Internet Explorer.  I am using Internet explorer 11 and I have implemented a fix suggested on the nervgh/afu site which includes a shim and sham file for older browsers. IE 11 isn't older but thought I'd give it a try.

The code is standard for the library so there really isn't anything to show.  I do have this error now though but I don't know what it's telling me?

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: precisionfarming
onAfterAddingAll [object Object]
"onAfterAddingAll"
[
  0: { },
  length: 1
]

onBeforeUploadItem [object Object]
"onBeforeUploadItem"
{
  [functions]: ,
  $$hashKey: "object:105",
  __proto__: { },
  _file: { },
  _input: null,
  alias: "file",
  disableMultipart: false,
  file: { },
  formData: [ ],
  headers: { },
  index: 1,
  isCancel: false,
  isError: false,
  isReady: true,
  isSuccess: false,
  isUploaded: false,
  isUploading: false,
  method: "POST",
  progress: 0,
  removeAfterUpload: false,
  uploader: { },
  url: "undefinedapi/UploadFiles",
  withCredentials: false
}

onProgressItem [object Object] 1
"onProgressItem"
{
  [functions]: ,
  $$hashKey: "object:105",
  __proto__: { },
  _file: { },
  _input: null,
  _xhr: { },
  alias: "file",
  disableMultipart: false,
  file: { },
  formData: [ ],
  headers: { },
  index: 1,
  isCancel: false,
  isError: false,
  isReady: true,
  isSuccess: false,
  isUploaded: false,
  isUploading: true,
  method: "POST",
  progress: 1,
  removeAfterUpload: false,
  uploader: { },
  url: "undefinedapi/UploadFiles",
  withCredentials: false
}
1

onProgressAll 1
onProgressItem [object Object] 100
"onProgressItem"
{
  [functions]: ,
  $$hashKey: "object:105",
  __proto__: { },
  _file: { },
  _input: null,
  _xhr: { },
  alias: "file",
  disableMultipart: false,
  file: { },
  formData: [ ],
  headers: { },
  index: 1,
  isCancel: false,
  isError: false,
  isReady: true,
  isSuccess: false,
  isUploaded: false,
  isUploading: true,
  method: "POST",
  progress: 100,
  removeAfterUpload: false,
  uploader: { },
  url: "undefinedapi/UploadFiles",
  withCredentials: false
}
100

onProgressAll 100
onCompleteItem [object Object] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 
Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-
serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-s
"onCompleteItem"
{
  [functions]: ,
  $$hashKey: "object:105",
  __proto__: { },
  _file: { },
  _input: null,
  _xhr: { },
  alias: "file",
  disableMultipart: false,
  file: { },
  formData: [ ],
  headers: { },
  index: null,
  isCancel: false,
  isError: true,
  isReady: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isUploaded: true,
  isUploading: false,
  method: "POST",
  progress: 0,
  removeAfterUpload: false,
  uploader: { },
  url: "undefinedapi/UploadFiles",
  withCredentials: false
}
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-
serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC000"
404
{
  [functions]: ,
  __proto__: { },
  cache-control: "private",
  content-length: "4935",
  content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  date: "Mon, 11 Dec 2017 18:34:14 GMT",
  persistent-auth: "true",
  server: "Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
  x-powered-by: "ASP.NET"
}

onCompleteAll
```

I'm really looking for someone that has had some success with this library in IE. I've also posted a question to the GIT site and will be happy to update this question if someone there can help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Show your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, It turns out that the problem didn't have anything to do with the Angular-File-Upload library it was actually how different browsers get the host URL which I use to call a controller.

The Angular-File-Upload JavaScript code that defines the file uploader look lsike this...

```
var singleUploader = this.singleUploader = new FileUploader({
        url: baseURI + "api/UploadFiles",
        service: this.service,
        formValues: this.FormValues,            
    });
```

as you can see you can pass several properties from your controller into the FileUploader object to be used.  The property that was tripping me up was "url".

I Chrome and FireFox

```
document.baseURI;
```

will return "http://hostname:port/nameofsite/"  however in IE this does not work so I was passing in "undefined"  which obviously will not work.

I changed my code as follows...

```
var baseURI = document.baseURI;
    if (baseURI == undefined) {
        baseURI = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname 
+ (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '') + "/MySiteName/";

    };

    var singleUploader = this.singleUploader = new FileUploader({
        url: baseURI + "api/UploadFiles",
        service: this.service,
        formValues: this.FormValues,

    });
```

Now everything is happy and works!!